# How to calculate the t-statistics over many estimated coefficients (for the same variable, but across years) in r?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, t-test

I am working on a paper replication project and i need some advice on the following issue. The baseline regression is in the form:

```
model <- feols(y_t2 ~ x1_t1 + x2, data = dat, fsplit = ~year)
```

This regression is ran across years. Assume there are in total 20 years, there are in total 20 annual cross-sectional regressions with 20 estimated coefficients for the key independent variable `x1_t`. How could I calculate the t-statistics of the 20 estimated coefficients in R, i.e., how do i get the correct estimated standard errors of the 20 coefficients (for each regression there is an estimated coefficient and standard errors computed)?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Using `CO2` (which comes with R) and also `lmList` from nlme (which comes from R so no installation required) we can calculate the t values of conc by Plant like this:

```
library(nlme)
coef(summary(lmList(uptake ~ conc | Plant, CO2)))[, , "conc"][, "t value"]
```

giving

```
      Qn1       Qn2       Qn3       Qc1       Qc3       Qc2       Mn3       Mn2 
2.3727920 3.2797927 2.9829021 2.7215324 3.1578555 3.2725825 1.7544113 1.9517375 
      Mn1       Mc2       Mc3       Mc1 
2.9368841 0.6942998 0.8113596 1.3932651
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the quick reply!! This helps a lot. Beside the t values for each group, i want to compute one mean and one t value for all groups altogether, can i calculate that by taking the mean of all t values from the groups?